# Error loading Pretrained vectors on gensim 0.12

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am calling load like this .

.7/dist-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 912, in

```
  model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("F:\\TrialGrounds\\gensimMODEL4\\model4") 

model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 248, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2unpickle
    return _pickle.loads(f.read())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call_on_class_only'
```

The model has split 500mb *2 numpy arrays. Can anyone help me in figuring out this issue

Answer (score 2):

Are you by chance trying to load a model made in a later version of gensim into an earlier version? (The `call_on_class_only` method, for the purposes of warning about a common error, was only added in December 2016, whereas the latest 0.12.x release was in January 2016.)

While gensim tries to maintain the ability of older models to be loaded in newer versions, the reverse can be quite a bit harder. Try using a later gensim version where you're loading the model.

(If you really needed a workaround, you could possibly load the model in a later version, `del model.call_on_class_only` to eliminate the not-strictly-needed function reference, and then re-save... and it *might* then `load()` into an older version. But being version-equivalent and version-up-to-date everywhere would be better.)

Comment: Hi gojomo, I got the same issue. But my versions are similar (0.12.3). Please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978579/error-when-loading-the-word2vec-model

Comment: Your code doesn't show you trying the workaround above. Did you try it?

Comment: I updated the question. Please kindly let me know if you know a way to solve this :)